# Where does zypper source-install put the sources?

Tags: opensuse, rpm, suse, zypper

When using a command like

```
zypper source-install kwrite
```

where does zypper install the sources to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found them at `/usr/src/packages/SOURCES/<SomeName>`